# Kendo UI - Specify parameter name on dataSource read

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-ui

With **Kendo UI**, I am using an autocomplete box to try and retrieve data from my server. It is hitting an **ASP.NET MVC** controller with the following signature.

```
public ActionResult aspect(string term){
   // ...
}
```

This means that the request needs to have the correct parameter in the url. Now the issue I am running into is that I cannot discover a way to specify this in the **dataSource** mechanics. I have read the documentation on **parameterMap** dozens of times and it makes absolutely no sense to me in any way.

This is complicated further by the fact that the page in question actually has 10-15 *autocomplete* text boxes at any one time, each dynamically created with dynamic identity.

The code I am using so far is as follows;

```
$(".autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/search/aspect"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So is there anything I can do to tell it how to name the parameter it passes?

To make it more clear what I am trying to do, if I were doing this in *jQuery*, I would use ...

```
$.ajax({ url: '/search/aspects', data: { term: (insert the data here) } });
```

But because of the way all of this works, there is no set "selector" to get the autocomplete input, so I cannot retrieve its value from the input form element.

Comment: Did you try checking [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/serverfiltering.html) example? In the code part don't forget to click on ASP.NET MVC and then the different source files.

Comment: I am not using the version of Kendo that has the MVC Razor tools. That example is where I started, but it is not useful to me unfortunately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, enable server-side filtering by setting this option:

```
dataSource: {
    serverFiltering: true,
```

Then the value is passed as one of the parameters into the `transport.parameterMap` function.

If you were to log the object passed in to the parameterMap function like this:

```
$(".autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataSource: {
        serverFiltering: true,
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/search/aspect"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, action) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

then you would get an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "filter":{
        "logic":"and",
        "filters":[
            {
                "value":"something",
                "operator":"contains",
                "field":"Name",
                "ignoreCase":true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So you can use this to get the value entered into the AutoComplete box by doing:

```
$(".autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataSource: {
        serverFiltering: true,
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/search/aspect"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, action) {
                if(action === "read") {
                    return {
                        term: data.filter.filters[0].value
                    };
                } else {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It sounds like you understand what I am trying to do, but the code you posted returns this error.. _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filters' of undefined_. I'm attempting to do some debugging now to find out why.

Comment: Attempting to do as you have said and log the object passed through the data function simply yields "_{}_"

Comment: I edited my answer. I forgot to also mention that you need to enable `serverFiltering` on the DataSource so that it passes the entered text into the `data()` function. Sorry about that.

Comment: That got some progress, but it is still behaving strangely. It tries to use the url .. _http://localhost:60600/search/aspect?term=statistic&filter%5Blogic%5D=and&filt…ld%5D=Name&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5BignoreCase%5D=true&_=1379719337398_

Comment: Ugh, sorry, I edited my answer again. It looks like using `read.data` combines the returned result into the other data items passed to the server. `parameterMap` can be used instead to replace all the data passed to the server. I updated my answer to use `parameterMap` instead. I also rigged up an example and used fiddler to check the request to make sure this edit works.

Comment: Though as a side note, even with the full filter info in your URL, the MVC action should have still been called correctly. The extra query string parameters just won't be mapped to function parameters.

Comment: This wouldn't be so bad if the Kendo documentation were more clear on how to use some of this. I'll be plugging this in in a moment, thanks for your patience with me.

Comment: Hrnm, even with that update, it is still the strange, long URL with the bad parameters. I'm copying your code verbatim.

Comment: oh man I am having an epic night of wrong answers here... :)  OK, I edited my answer again. When I typed that code, I made the function `dataSource.parameterMap` but is actually goes under `transport` so should be `dataSource.transport.parameterMap`. Sorry for all the edits :(

Comment: It's alright, it isn't your job to write my code for me. I've been tinkering with it too, and came to the same conclusion at about the same time. Thanks so much for all of your help. This finally works right! I cannot express enough how thankful I am.

Comment: I think it is also worth noting that you were correct the very first time you posted. It is my own inadequate incompetence that did not work. Your code was flawless, but I had the action method marked `[HttpPost]` and not `[HttpGet]`, so it kept returning an error. You have made no mistakes, you simply showed me not one, but FIVE ways to complete what I was asking for. If anything you ought to get a medal for putting up with me.

Answer (score 6):

I think that there is a misunderstanding about the relation between `DataSource` and `AutoComplete`. `AutoComplete` has the `input` and uses a `DataSource` for retrieving the data: the `input` does not belong to the `AutoComplete` and as consequence you cannot get the `input` that is using a `DataSource` from a method that is from the `DataSource` (as `transport.read.data` or `transport.parameterMap`).

You need to unique identify which element has the input and the value that it contains.

What I do propose is getting the value using `document.activeElement.value`. Since you are typing it, the element that has the focus should be the element that you are using.

The code would be:

```
$(".autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/search/aspect",
            },
            parameterMap : function (data, type) {
                if (type === "read") {
                    return { term : document.activeElement.value }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Alternatively, you can enable `serverFiltering` and then Kendo UI links the `input` field with the filtering condition. The code would be:

```
$(".autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataSource   : {
        serverFiltering: true,
        type           : "json",
        transport      : {
            read        : {
                url : "/search/aspect"
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                if (type === "read") {
                    return { term : data.filter.filters[0].value }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This also accomplished my needs. However, I hope you understand, `CodingWithSpike` got to it first and therefore I awarded him the credit. I do not have enough reputation to upvote yours, but I will remember it and come back to it when I do. Thank you very much, it is very appreciated.

Comment: Also, this "_document.activeElement.value_" thing is awesome! Thank you!

Comment: using _document.activeElement_ seems to be the option how to get the input field itself to get further information, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little confused as to what you're wanting to do. If you are just trying to pass the string term to the controller you can specify the data:

```
$(".autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/search/aspect",
                data: { term: "value" }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't work either. If I knew how to retrieve the data to put in place of "value", I would have it solved. But I cannot figure out how to get that is the problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the autocomplete widget (or the datasource control) does not provide a way to get the value it is currently trying to pass. The only way I have found is to do it by specific selector, which isn't possible in my given situation.

Comment: I have added a bit more to the question to try and make it clearer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification and help OnaBai. Here is the code that I got working after hours of frustration!

```
$("#contractsSearchField").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    autoBind: false,
    placeholder:'select...',
    filter: "contains",// a filter must be present for the datasources serverFiltering argument to work properly.
    minLength: 3,
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({ 
        serverFiltering: true,//We must turn on serverFiltering and sorting, otherwise, the combobox only works once and will not change it's values.
        serverSorting: true,
        group: { field: "searchtype" },
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "contract.cfc?method=getContractForDropdown",
                // We are not passing the data here like we do in the autosuggest. The combobox is a different type of an animal.
                dataType: "json",  
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // Note: when posting json via the request body to a coldfusion page, we must use this content type or we will get a 'IllegalArgumentException' on the ColdFusion processing page.                 
                type: "GET"
            },//read
            // Pass the search term that was typed in by the user. This works because when the user types into the input box, it becomes that active element in the form.
            parameterMap : function (data, type) {
                if (type === "read") {
                    return { searchTerm : document.activeElement.value }
                    //return { searchTerm: data.filter.filters[0].value }
                }
            }//parameterMap
        }//transport
    })//dataSource
}); //...kendoComboBox...
```