# Get search string in kendo multiselect with server filtering

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have a kendo multi select with server filtering as below.

```
$("#ddlAnalysisTeamMember_" + _WidgetID).kendoMultiSelect(
    {
        autoBind: false,
        minLength: 3,
        //placeholder: 'User Name',
        dataTextField: 'Text',
        dataValueField: 'ID',
        filter: 'contains',
        autoClose: false,
        delay: 200,
        dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: _VirDir("GetUsernameMultiAutoComplete", "LoadController"),
                    dataType: 'json'
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

**What I need?**

I need to get the search string user enter in the box, say user enter "apple" to search and check if there is any html in that. If there is any html type, i need to raise an alert() and stop server call for filtering.

---

**What I did so far?**

I tried the virtual in multiselect like this

```
      virtual: {
                itemHeight: 26,
                valueMapper: function (options) {
                    alert(options.value);
                }
            },
            dataSource: {
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: _VirDir("GetUsernameMultiAutoComplete", "WidgetsLoad"),
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }
                }
            },
```

But this is not working.

**Update 11/28/2016**

I got the search string user enter using below code. And successfully validate the string and show the validation message.

```
dataSource: {
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: _VirDir("GetUsernameMultiAutoComplete", "WidgetsLoad"),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function () {
                var searchText = $.trim($("#ddlAnalysisTeamMember_" + _WidgetID).data('kendoMultiSelect').input.val());
                if(searchText.showDangerousString()){// show error message div if restricted chars found.
                // block server request
                e.preventDefault(); // not working. a server request is going
                return false; // not working. a server request is going
                } 
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even if i tried `e.preventDefault()` and `return false;` the server call is going.

Is there any way to stop the server call?

---

Is there any events to capture what user enter in the multiselect before it is sent to server to filter out the data?

Is there any way to get the user entered search text?

**Update 11/28/2016**

Is there any way to stop sending a server request from data function inside datasource?

Comment: I solve this with the help of this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925779/kendo-ui-specify-parameter-name-on-datasource-read

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for it right now, you can [get the value from value function](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index) or validate it on client side and also on server side.